# Switch cases are not getting executed properly

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

case 1 and default cases are not working properly print statement is not getting executed. I'm unable to identify the error. I don't know if there is problem with the scanner implementation it seems fine to me.

```
import java.util.*;
public class StartApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        String categoryName="";
        int ch=0;   
        Scanner sc1=new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc2=new Scanner(System.in);
        Logger.getInstance().log("Starting task manager", 1);   
        while(ch!=7)
        {
            System.out.println("press 1 to create category");
            System.out.println("press 2 to load category");
            System.out.println("press 3 to remove catergory");
            System.out.println("press 4 to list category");
            System.out.println("press 5 to search category");
            System.out.println("press 6 to export");
            System.out.println("press 7 to exit");
            ch=sc1.nextInt();
        }
        switch(ch)
        {
        case 1:{
            System.out.println("enter category name");
            categoryName=sc2.nextLine();
            sc2.nextLine();
            while(!ProjectUtility.validateName(categoryName))
            {
                System.out.println("category name must be one word. It cannot contain a numbers,spaces and Alpanumerics.");
                categoryName=sc2.nextLine();
            }
            break;}
        case 7:
            System.out.println("exiting...");
        break;
        default:
            System.out.println("option not supported");
            break;
        }
        }
        catch(Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you're stuck in that first `while` unless you select 7

Comment: @akarnokd they'll never reach any use of the second scanner unless they select "7"  in the first input, which will then promptly end the program. My impression (especially judging by the wonky indentation) is that they put the closing brace of the `while` loop too early.

Comment: It should be `while(ch <= 0 || ch > 7)`.

Comment: thanks @NiceBooks  its working properly now

Comment: So this question is closed or did you still need an Answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You will only get out of your while loop if the condition `while(ch!=7){...}` turns false. So your switch label '7' is the only reachable in the whole switch. The Solution is to put your switch in your while loop.
2. You only need one Scanner and you should close it at the end

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
           String categoryName = "";
           int ch = 0;
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           Logger.getInstance().log("Starting task manager", 1);
           while (ch != 7) {
               System.out.println("press 1 to create category");
               System.out.println("press 2 to load category");
               System.out.println("press 3 to remove catergory");
               System.out.println("press 4 to list category");
               System.out.println("press 5 to search category");
               System.out.println("press 6 to export");
               System.out.println("press 7 to exit");
               System.out.println();
               System.out.print("input: ");
               ch = sc.nextInt();

               switch (ch) {
                   case 1: {
                       System.out.print("enter category name: ");
                       categoryName = sc.nextLine();
                       sc.nextLine();
                       while (!ProjectUtility.validateName(categoryName)) {
                           System.out.println("category name must be one word. It cannot contain a numbers,spaces and Alpanumerics.");
                           System.out.print("enter category name: ");
                           categoryName = sc.nextLine();
                       }
                       break;
                   }
                   case 7:
                       System.out.println("exiting...");
                       break;
                   default:
                       System.out.println("option not supported");
                       break;
               }
           }
           sc.close();
       } catch (Throwable t) {
           t.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```